# Dynamic variable names in function in R

Tags: r, variables, vector, rename

I am looking to make a function that takes a vector as input, does some simple arithmetic with the vector and call the new vector something which consists of a set string (say, "log.") plus the original vector name.

```
d = c(1 2, 3)
my.function <- function { x
x2 <- log(x)
...
```

I would like the function to return a vector called log.d (that is, not log.x or something set, but something dependent on the name of the vector input as x).

Comment: Don't do this. The proper way is `log.d <- yourfunction(d)`. Side effects like the one you want are evil and not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try next:

```
d = c(1, 2, 3)

my.function <- function(x){
    x2 <- log(x)

    arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) # Get argument name
    var_name <- paste("log", arg_name, sep="_") # Construct the name
    assign(var_name, x2, env=.GlobalEnv) # Assign values to variable
    # variable will be created in .GlobalEnv 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works like a charm!

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa but beware... `my.function(my.function(d))` doesn't return `log.log.d` as you might hope. This function doesn't play nicely with itself, let alone other  functions like `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to store separately names of all your input vector names and then pass them to `assign` function. Like `assign` takes text string for output object name, `get` looks up object from string.

I will assume your vectors all follow common pattern and start with "d", to make it all as dynamic as possible.

```
d1 <- c(1,2,3)
d2 <- c(2,3,4)

vec_names <- ls(pattern = "^d")

log_vec <- function(x){
  log(x)
}

sapply(vec_names, function(x) assign(paste0("log.", x), log_vec(get(x)), envir = globalenv()))
```

This should create two new objects "log.d1" and "log.d2".